# How can I merge these tow block of code together to simplify it?

Tags: javascript

I'm checking two different divs after a setTimeOut of 2 seconds to see if they contain an iFrame or not. If they don't I just set their display to none to hide them.
Important is that these two divs never exist together on one page.
Now I put the following code together and it's working fine:

```
let divOne = document.querySelector('.div-one')
if (divOne) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let divOneIframe = divOne.querySelector("iframe")

        if (!divOneIframe) {
            divOne.style["display"] = "none";
        }
    }, 2000)
}

let divTow = document.querySelector('.div-two')
if (divTow) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let divTwoIframe = divTow.querySelector("iframe")

        if (!divTwoIframe) {
            divTow.style["display"] = "none";
        }
    }, 2000)
}
```

But it doesn't seem right to me to have to separate setTimeOut for it.

How can I merged these two block of codes so that I end up with using setTimeOut only once?

Comment: put the code from one into the other? have you made an attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating over an array of those possible selectors would work.

```
const div = ['.div-one', '.div-two']
    .map(sel => document.querySelector(sel))
    .find(Boolean);
if (div) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const iframe = div.querySelector('iframe');
        if (!iframe) {
            div.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

With optional chaining:

Another approach would be to give `.div-one` and `.div-two` their own selector in common - eg, have `<div class="div-one contains-iframe">` and `<div class="div-two contains-iframe">` so that you only have to select `.contains-iframe` rather than iterate.

Comment: can't you just `let div = document.querySelector('.div-one') || document.querySelector('.div-two')`?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: @IvanAmbla You can, but using an array makes it easier and DRYer if the code has to be tweaked again in the future.